# Draw String to centre of ellipse

Tags: c#, drawing

I have simple code, which can draw an ellipse. I want draw a number at the center of this ellipse, how can I do this?

Code for drawing the ellipse is:

```
Point point = p.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
float radius = 13.0f;
float x = point.X - radius;
float y = point.Y - radius;
float width = 2 * radius;
float height = 2 * radius;
graphicsObj.FillEllipse(myBrush, x, y, width, height);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Graphics.DrawString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa327573(v=vs.71).aspx) to draw text in center of surrounding rectangle. Specify an [StringFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformat(v=vs.110).aspx) object with Alignment and LineAlignment set to StringAlignment.Center:

```
RectangleF bounds = new RectangleF(x, y, width, height);
using (StringFormat format = new StringFormat()) {
    format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    graphicsObj.DrawText("Number", SystemFonts.Default, Brushes.Black, bounds, format);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using:

```
public void FillEllipse(
    Brush brush,
    Rectangle rect
)
```

and

```
public void DrawString(
    string s,
    Font font,
    Brush brush,
    RectangleF layoutRectangle
)
```

which is:

```
graphicsObj.FillEllipse(brush,rect);
graphicsObj.DrawString("Number Here", new Font("Arial", 13f), Brushes.Black, sameRectangleOfEllipse);
```